# How to save the id and the model in polymorphic (laravel 6)?

Tags: laravel, controller

I try these to save my comments:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

and

```
class Review extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }

}
```

the routes:

```
Route::get('/reviews', 'front\ReviewController@Holder')->name('ReviewHolder');
Route::get('/reviews/{slug}', 'front\ReviewController@index')->name('Review');
Route::post('/reviews', 'front\ReviewController@Sendcm')->name('SendComment');
```

and my controller:

```
class ReviewController extends Controller
{
    public function Holder(){
        $reviews = Review::latest()->with('partners')->paginate(6);
        return view('front.review.holder.main', compact('reviews'));
    }

    public function index($slug){
        $item = Review::where('slug','=', $slug)->with('partners')->first();
        return view('front.review.main.main',compact('item'));
    }

    public function Sendcm(Request $request){
        $review = Review::find($id);
        $comment = new Comment;
        $comment->name = $request->name;
        $comment->email = $request->email;
        $comment->body = $request->body;
        $review->comments()->save($comment);
        return redirect()->back();

    }
}
```

but i can't save the comment and show me an error

> Undefined variable: id

how to find the id and model from my blade or in another way to save the comments?
and i try the:

```
public function Sendcm(Request $request, $slug){
$review = Review::find($slug);
$comment = new Comment;
.
.
.}
```

but the error is:

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\front\ReviewController::Sendcm(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Comment: please tell what is `$slug`? you have to add this parameter in your function probably

Comment: slug is my url foreach of my review e.g. "reviews/joker2019-review", and you can see in my routes & controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a little the above answer in Controller to the:

```
public function Sendcm(Request $request, $slug){
        $review = Review::find($slug);
        $comment = new Comment;
        $comment->name = $request->name;
        $comment->email = $request->email;
        $comment->body = $request->body;
        $review->comments()->save($comment);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

and

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => route('send_comment', $item->id), 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

and the routes to:

```
Route::post('/reviews/{review}', 'front\ReviewController@Sendcm')->name('send_comment');
```

an now it's working but save the commentable_type without the 'App\' in comments table

Answer (score 1):

Undefined variable `$id` is because the function doesn't know where the `$id` is coming from. One option is to inject the `review` model as the second parameter like so:

```
public function Sendcm(Request $request, Review $review){
  $review = Review::find($slug); //you can get rid of this.
  $comment = new Comment;
  .
}
```

Then update your route like so:

```
Route::post('/reviews/{review}', 'front\ReviewController@Sendcm')->name('SendComment');
```

Laravel will automatically give you the Review model associated with the `id` you post.

The error in the second example is because you did not update your route to accept a second parameter. You could have avoided that error by updating your route like so:

```
Route::post('/reviews/{slug}', 'front\ReviewController@Sendcm')->name('SendComment');
```

On a different note, it is advisable to follow PSR standards and Laravel's naming conventions. In that regard, it is best if you use snake case with dot notation while naming your routes. So, `SendComment` is better as `reviews.send_comment`

Comment: i try it: Undefined variable: slug on reviews/{slug} & 404 on reviews/{review} and i change my blade to {!! Form::open(['url' => route('send_comment', $item->slug), 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

Comment: What happens when you change your form to `Form::open(['url' => route('send_comment', $item->id), 'method' => 'POST']) !!}` and your route `..('review/{review}'..)->name('send_comment');`?

Comment: ErrorException  Undefined variable: slug for the " $review = Review::find($slug)"